# Polar representation of a 2-dimensional Gaussian random variable

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X = R\cos\Theta$ and $Y = R\sin\Theta$ be two independent, standard normally distributed random variables, written in polar coordinates.

How do we prove that the random variable $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed in $[0, 2\pi]$?

Comment: I don't think that is necessarily true; $\Theta$ could be uniformly distributed on $[0,4\pi]$ for instance.

Comment: @nejimban: In polars, $\Theta$ is the angle over (0;360°) thus the distribution of $\Theta$ being $f(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is evidently uniform on $(0;2\pi)$. See my answer for details

Comment: @tommik I agree, but one could “factorize” differently, e.g., $\frac1{4\pi}\cdot2re^{-r^2/2}$… One could also take $\Theta$ uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. It is kind of implicit that $\Theta$ be valued in $[0,2\pi]$ then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$$

passing in polars you get

$$f_{R\Theta}(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot r e^{-r^2/2}$$

that is

$$f_{R\Theta}(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;2\pi)}(\theta)\times r e^{-r^2/2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;\infty)}(r)=f_{\Theta}(\theta)\times f_R(r)$$

where

$$\Theta \sim U(0;2\pi)$$

$$R\sim \text{Rayleigh}(1)$$

---

[Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform.